# Session.cookie_domain in php.ini

Tags: php, session-cookies, ini

I have been reading as much as possible about the php.ini file and i have found nothing about whether or not its bad/dangerous to not set the session.cookie_domain in the php.ini.

We are in a production environment and this is not set.

Are there security issues with not setting this. Cookies appear to be working well, no real issues.

The php.ini file looks like this:

```
session.cookie_domain =
```

Answer (score 0):

### Original answer (Edited to remove incorrect parts)

I disagree with the accepted answer. I think `session.cookie_domain` is not a configuration directive that allow you to **restrict** subdomains but to **allow** subdomains. If you read [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain), it says if the value of the directive is not defined (none, default value) then the host name of the machine that generated the cookie is used as cookie domain.

> ```
>  session.cookie_domain specifies the domain to set in the session cookie. Default is none at all meaning the host name of the server which generated the cookie according to cookies specification. See also session_get_cookie_params() and session_set_cookie_params().
> ```

Also, by default, PHP is configured so that sessions are unique to a domain.
If you don't specify one but if the domain of the server is example.org, your cookies will be valid only for example.org domain, and invalid for any sub-domain like `app.example.org` or any other domain like `corp.com`.

The goal of `session.cookie_domain` is to actually **allow** the usage of sub-domains, so if you set `session.cookie_domain = "example.org"` it will act as a wildcard and accept any sub-domains.

So setting a wildcard `session.cookie_domain = "example.org"` is way more open to attacks than not setting it.

### Updated answer

By reading [Set-Cookie - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#domaindomain-value) and [Using HTTP cookies - HTTP - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#domain_attribute), it seems that PHP behavior is deprecated.

> `Domain=<domain-value>`
>
> Defines the host to which the cookie will be sent.
>
> If omitted, this attribute defaults to the host of the current document URL, not including subdomains.
>
> Contrary to earlier specifications, leading dots in domain names (.example.com) are ignored.
>
> Multiple host/domain values are not allowed, but if a domain is specified, then subdomains are always included.

Also

> The Domain attribute specifies which hosts can receive a cookie. If
> unspecified, the attribute defaults to the same host that set the
> cookie, excluding subdomains. If Domain is specified, then subdomains
> are always included. Therefore, specifying Domain is less restrictive
> than omitting it. However, it can be helpful when subdomains need to
> share information about a user.
>
> For example, if you set Domain=mozilla.org, cookies are available on
> subdomains like developer.mozilla.org.

It seems that current behavior is to ignore leading dot and to implicitly allow all subdomains when you specify a domain. So in fact, the final answer is that using `Domain` is less secure that not using it. So the reality is exactly the opposite of the accepted answer.

Comment: Running PHP8.2.0RC4 that seems to not be correct at the comment. A no-value set for the `cookie.domian` is resulting in that cookie being shared to the sub-domains. Maybe a bug, will submit a report.